# How to know which stack is clicked, in a grouped stacked bar (chartjs)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I created a bar chart similar to the picture. I am using two stacks as a group. Every stack might have multiple datasets. I am using Vue.js and vue-chartjs.

[image]

I am using following `onClick` option of Chart.js, `e` is the event and `i` is array of datasets used in the chart. By knowing the index of one of datasets we know which group is clicked. In this way,I know which group is clicked on. However I need to know which stack is clicked on.

```
onClick: (e, i ) => {
  console.log(i[0]._index)
}
```

Data which i am using for chart:

```
this.datacollection = {
  labels: [...Object.keys(total)],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Started',
      stack: 'Stack 0',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(112,108,236,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(112,108,236,0.3)',
      borderWidth: 5,
      data: Object.values(active)
    },
    {
      label: 'Assigned (all)',
      stack: 'Stack 0',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(137,37,252 , 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(137,37,252 , 0.2)',
      borderWidth: 5,
      data: Object.values(total),
    },
    {
      label: 'Finished',
      stack: 'Stack 0',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(30,135,246, 0.3)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(30,135,246, 0.4)',
      borderWidth: 5,
      data: Object.values(done)
    },
    {
      label: 'Rated',
      stack: 'Stack 0',
      backgroundColor: pattern.draw('dot-dash', 'rgb(98,241,58 , 0.5)'),
      borderColor: 'rgb(98,241,58 , 0.5)',
      borderWidth: 5,
      data: Object.values(rated)
    },
    {
      label: 'Trashed',
      stack: 'Stack 1',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(236,108,127,0.5)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(236,108,127,0.5)',
      borderWidth: 5,
      data: Object.values(trashed)
    },
  ]
}
```

and this is option of the chart

```
{
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        stacked: true
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        stacked: false
      }
    ]
  },
  onClick: (e, i) => { console.log(i[0]._index) }
}
```

**Above information might be enough for you, but if You like to see the full code:**
**test.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <bar-chart :chart-data="datacollection" :options="options"></bar-chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BarChart from '@/components/Charts/BarChart.js'
import pattern from 'patternomaly';

export default {
  components: {
    BarChart,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datacollection: null,
      loaded: false,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{stacked: true}],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            },
            stacked: false
          }]
        },
        onClick: (e, i ) => {
            console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fillData()
  },
  methods: {
    fillData() {
      this.loaded = false;

      window.axios.get('/api/reports/tests', {
        params: {
          dateRange: this.dateRange
        }
      })
        .then((res) => {
          let total = res.data.total;
          let done = res.data.done;
          let active = res.data.active;
          let trashed = res.data.trashed;
          let rated = res.data.rated;

          this.datacollection = {
            labels: [...Object.keys(total)],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Started',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(112,108,236,0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(112,108,236,0.3)',
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: Object.values(active)
              },
              {
                label: 'Assigned (all)',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(137,37,252 , 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(137,37,252 , 0.2)',
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: Object.values(total),
              },
              {
                label: 'Finished',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(30,135,246, 0.3)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(30,135,246, 0.4)',
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: Object.values(done)
              },
              {
                label: 'Rated',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                backgroundColor: pattern.draw('dot-dash', 'rgb(98,241,58 , 0.5)'),
                borderColor: 'rgb(98,241,58 , 0.5)',
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: Object.values(rated)
              },
              {
                label: 'Trashed',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(236,108,127,0.5)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(236,108,127,0.5)',
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: Object.values(trashed)
              },
            ]
          }
          this.loaded = true;
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**BarChart.js:**

```
import { Bar , mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['chartData' , 'options'],
  mounted () {
    if (this.chartdata)
      this.renderChart(this.chartdata)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62432563/2358409

Answer (score 0):

I found a way usign `chart.getElementAtEvent(evt)`

```
let chart = this.$refs.barChart.$data._chart;

                let datasetIndex = chart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0]._datasetIndex

                let stack = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).stack;
```